# I get an error how to write new data into existing json file using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I get an error, how to write new data into existing JSON file using angularjs? I used `$http.post` method to add new data to my file but it's not getting added, but am getting the success message in the alert box.

If I changed the name of the file its showing failed message in alert.

```
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http) { 
                        var url="customer.json";
                        $http.get(url).success( function(data) {
                        $scope.customers = data;
                      });
                       $scope.addUser=function(name,email,phone){
                       var dataObject = {
                       Name : "robin"
                      ,email  : "robin"
                      ,password  : 123,
                      phone:123
                    };

                    var write = $http.post("customer.json", dataObject);
                    write.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      console.log(data.title);
                      alert("Submitting form success!");

                    });
                    write.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      alert("Submitting form failed!");
                    }); 
                    }
                    };
                 // am getting the success message but its not adding         the                new        data into customer.json file

                    here is my json file
                    ====================
                    [
                    {
                    "Name" : "Mahesh Parashar",
                    "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
                    "password" : 123,
                    "phone":1111
                    },
                    {
                    "Name" : "Dinkar Kad",
                    "email" : "def@gmail.com",
                    "password" : 123,
                    "phone":2222
                    },
                    {
                    "Name" : "Robert",
                    "email" : "jkl@gmail.com",
                    "password" : 123,
                    "phone":333
                    },
                    {
                    "Name" : "Julian Joe", 
                    "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
                    "password" : 123,
                    "phone":444
                    }
                    ]//this is ma customer.json file
```

Comment: You  must show server code for writing api

Comment: Your file is at server.So you have to write server code to write data in that file

Comment: i didnt get wht you ment by server code. am saved my customer.json file in ma local drive

Comment: please some one help me to write server code

Comment: i just want to add dataObject to my customer.json file using $http.post

Comment: @RobinThomas and who is listening to $http.post request???

Comment: can u go through with ma code?